# Rspec shared definitions loaded twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I haven't been able to pinpoint the cause of this, but I'm getting deprecation warnings of shared specs being loaded more than once in a Rails project. Here's how they are defined:

# spec/support/shared/authenticated_endpoints_spec.rb

```
RSpec.shared_examples "an authenticated endpoint" do
  it_behaves_like "an authenticated show endpoint"
  it_behaves_like "an authenticated index endpoint"
end

RSpec.shared_examples "an authenticated show endpoint" do
# omitted
end
RSpec.shared_examples "an authenticated index endpoint" do
# omitted
end
```

My `spec_helper` looks like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
end
```

This is the Deprecation warning I've been getting:

```
WARNING: Shared example group 'an authenticated endpoint' has been previously defined at:
  /Users/me/my_proj/spec/support/shared/authenticated_endpoints_shared_spec.rb:1
...and you are now defining it at:
  /Users/me/my_proj/spec/support/shared/authenticated_endpoints_shared_spec.rb:1
The new definition will overwrite the original one.
WARNING: Shared example group 'an authenticated show endpoint' has been previously defined at:
  /Users/me/my_proj/spec/support/shared/authenticated_endpoints_shared_spec.rb:6
...and you are now defining it at:
  /Users/me/my_proj/spec/support/shared/authenticated_endpoints_shared_spec.rb:6
The new definition will overwrite the original one.
WARNING: Shared example group 'an authenticated index endpoint' has been previously defined at:
  /Users/me/my_proj/spec/support/shared/authenticated_endpoints_shared_spec.rb:36
...and you are now defining it at:
  /Users/me/my_proj/spec/support/shared/authenticated_endpoints_shared_spec.rb:36
The new definition will overwrite the original one.
```

I am not requiring these shared specs anywhere else (that I can find, anyway), in the test suite. I looked through `rspec-core` and there's a lot of meta programming going on that I don't quite understand.

Anyone have tips on how to debug this?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the reason is described [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/828). Since your file names are ended with "_spec.rb", they get autoloaded as examples by RSpec. What I did and what helped, is renaming the files, containing shared examples, removing the "_spec" portion.

Answer (score 4):

There's a closed [issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/623) on rspec-rails for this. Basically, RSpec uses a pattern matcher (`spec/**/*_spec.rb`) to find spec files and auto-loads them. But your spec helper auto-loads all files in the `spec/support/` subdirectory. So your `spec/support/shared/authenticated_endpoints_spec.rb` file is being loaded twice.

I'd suggest moving the `spec/support/shared/` subdirectory to `spec/shared`.

Comment: not sure I understand. If I remove the line that loads the files in my `spec_helper`, I get Not Found errors for these shared specs. Alternatively, if I move out the shared specs to `spec/shared`, I still have to load them somehow, right?

Comment: I've moved them to `spec/shared` and am individually requiring the shared specs where they are being used. Not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: Also had to remove the `_spec` from each of the shared example files.